# How to constrain the number of objects on the "many" side of a SQLAlchemy relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a relationship pattern like the one in the SQLAlchemy documentation (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = relationship('User', backref='addresses')
```

Is there any way to constrain that a `User` instance must have at least one `Address`?

In other words, this should fail:

```
user = User()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

...while this should succeed:

```
user = User()
address1 = Address(email_address='example1@example.com')
address2 = Address(email_address='example2@example.com')
user.addresses = [address1, address2]
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

Comment: One easy way would be to switch the owning side of the relationship -- that is, add an address_id to the User object. Another thing you could try is hooking into the 'before_insert' event of User. You should be able to raise an exception if address is None. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that a `User` could only have one `Address`? I want *at least* one.

Comment: Yup, my bad. I'd look into the ORM events.